# How to delete leading zeros in identifier such as "1.2.03.4"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Problem is to write sql script to delete leading zeros i MySQL database table in one column which represents identifires (numbers and dots).
I want to update values in db from example "1.2.03.4" to "1.2.3.4"

Comment: REPLACE or REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: Forgot to add - this is MySQL5.7 database and I want to delete only 3rd value to be leading zero repaced. So for example with value "1.02.03.04" script should save value "1.02.3.04"

Comment: Any leading double zeros expected?

Comment: Is there a case of `1.00.1.1`? And if there is what happens to the `00`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try `replace` for same. It seems like IP address, so you may check any `0` after `.` need to be removed i,e: `.0` replaces with '.' .

```
select replace ( @str, '.0','.')
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8+ has `regexp_replace()` which does exactly what you want:

```
select regexp_replace('1.2.03.00004', '[.]0+', '.')
```

EDIT:

If you want to replace only the leading zeros on the *third* value, then you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select concat_ws('.',
                 substring_index(col, '.', 2),
                 substring_index( substring_index(col, '.', 3), '.', -1 ) + 0,  -- convert to number
                 substring_index(col, '.', -1)
                )
```